# Dropdowns will automatically close when clicking them in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html-select

I have a div into which I load a dynamic content. Dynamic content is usually a form with multiple input elements, including dropdown menus. The problem is that sometimes dropdowns automatically close when clicking them. This happens only in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dynamic content does not fit into the placeholder div, a vertical scroll appears and you use it to scroll down to edit some form data there. If you load different content, IE still interprets it as the previous one and it "thinks" that you are scrolled all the way to the bottom, so the dropdowns here should not be visible (they are on top) and therefore automatically closes them.

You can check that by loading form content that does not fit into div, scroll down, edit some data (it's enough to click an input element; this way it will remember your cursor position), load another content (which fits into div) and load the previous one again. You will see that in IE the scroll will be somewhere in the middle (in Firefox and Chrome it will be scrolled all the way up).

The solution to my problem was to scroll the div to the top before loading new content:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('placeholder');
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```